# Change boot menu to a different partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows, ssd

Thanks for taking the time to look at my question.

I had to reinstall Ubuntu because I upgraded to an SSD.

Now I have Windows 10 on the SSD and Ubuntu 19.10 on my older HDD in dual boot.

But the problem is that you can also boot from the HDD but if you do it, it goes into automatic recovery and not into Windows itself.

What I want is using Ubuntu boot manager to also go to Windows.

I tried reinstalling a couple of times but even when I'm selecting it right, it keeps going to the HDD for Windows.

Even though I always select the SSD for the installation.

Can you change what partition it goes to in Ubuntu ?

Comment: Does Ubuntu boot OK and it's only Windows that doesn't boot?

Comment: Are both installs UEFI or both BIOS. With UEFI systems UEFI & BIOS are not compatible and once you start to boot in one mode or the other from UEFI boot menu, you cannot switch. Or grub only can boot other installs in same boot mode. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: UEFI and thanks good to know for next time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually fixed it in a stupid way. I cleared 50GB with Disk Genius and that made it work, using that free space.